# Refactoring build system to use Autotools

Tags: c++, c, autotools, autoconf, automake

Over the past couple of days I have been reading into using *autotools* to build my project instead of the Makefiles I have pieced together over the past couple of months. Unfortunately I have not found an example that gave me enough insight towards how my project structure is currently.

I have three libraries that are included in the application code of my project. I am looking for the best way to use a single configure script to make (and install) the application, and libraries.

Comment: Autotools documentation is kind of sparse. They arn't the simplest of tools either. Very Unixified.

Comment: So I've heard; the project I am working on I'd rather be easily deployed via GNU tool chain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few I found that don't look to bad:

1. http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html
2. http://www.developingprogrammers.com/index.php/2006/01/05/autotools-tutorial/
3. http://sources.redhat.com/autobook/

The last one is a free book

**Good Luck**

Comment: I've been using autotools for probably 10 years and still use the 'info automake' docs.  The #2 reference here has a useful picture to grasp what is generated.  I would also suggest finding an existing autotooled project such as the GNU ones that has the pattern you need - libs+app and see what they did.  I'd recommend separate dirs for each library and app.

Comment: But don't just copy paste from OSS. Licence apart, there are a lot of bad autotools examples out there.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for offtopic.

I did similar thing now, but I was able to choose between Autotools and CMake. I am happy to have choosen the second.

Might be worth looking at, including CDash, CTest and CPack.
http://www.cmake.org/

Best Regards,

Ovanes

Comment: Would you mind sharing some tutorials for cmake? The website just points to the book.

Comment: +1 for CMake once you get started it is very easy.  I use it for all my c++ projects even if I am just creating a small spike in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starter's guide to autoconf: http://amjith.blogspot.com/2009/04/autoconf-and-automake-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

When I read this, I was already pretty well familiar with the autotools, but it seems like a pretty good introduction:
[link text](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/books/autotools_a_guide_to_autoconf_automake_libtool)